# Creation of related Models on auth RegisterController in laravel

Tags: laravel, model

In my application, I have tables related to users and some of these tables require a row be inserted as soon as a `User` is registered.

For example, I have the following models:

`UserProfile`,
`UserAssignedRole`,
`UserSettings`

As soon as a User successfully registers, they will need a corresponding row in the DB.

I've done the following:

```
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        UserProfile::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
        ]);

        UserAssignedRole::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'role_id' => 1
        ]);

        UserSettings::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'nsfw' => 1
        ]);

        return $user;
    }
```

I'm looking for a better and more elegant way to achieve this. Is there a "Laravel" way in achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Larvel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) there's a chapter about **Recursively Saving Models & Relationships**. This is probably what you're looking for. They specify the following example:

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);

$post->comments[0]->message = 'Message';
$post->comments[0]->author->name = 'Author Name';

$post->push();
```

You could achieve something similar by creating a user including all its relationships in one `push()`.